# Live soccer board with time

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, timer

I am trying to call a sample API and build a live soccer score, but my time is not updating live without refresh. How to update the time without refresh?

Providing the stackblitz and code below. I looked at the console and there are no errors. I am able to call the sample API.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9ypawr?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Fstyle.css

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Scoreboard = () => {
  const [homeScore, setHomeScore] = useState(0);
  const [awayScore, setAwayScore] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setHomeScore(data[0].id);
        setAwayScore(data[1].id);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const timeInterval = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!timeInterval.current) {
      timeInterval.current = setInterval(() => {
        updateTime(); // Call the updateTime function every second
      }, 1000);
    }

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timeInterval.current); // Clear the interval when the component unmounts
    };
  }, []);

  const updateTime = () => {
    const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    const hours = new Date().getHours();
    const minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
    const seconds = new Date().getSeconds();

    const formattedTime = `${hours}:${minutes
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;

    document.getElementById(
      'home-time'
    ).textContent = `Last updated: ${formattedTime}`;
    document.getElementById(
      'away-time'
    ).textContent = `Last updated: ${formattedTime}`;
  };

  return (
    <div className="scoreboard">
      <div className="team">
        <img
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f8/Barcelona_logo.svg/220px-Barcelona_logo.svg.png"
          alt="Barcelona logo"
        />
        <h1>Barcelona</h1>
        <h2>{homeScore}</h2>
        <p id="home-time">Last updated: 00:00:00</p>
      </div>

      <div className="team">
        <img
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a2/Real_Madrid_CF.svg/220px-Real_Madrid_CF.svg.png"
          alt="Real Madrid logo"
        />
        <h1>Real Madrid</h1>
        <h2>{awayScore}</h2>
        <p id="away-time">Last updated: 00:00:00</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Scoreboard;
```

Comment: @JaromandaX can you tell me why the time is not updating?

Comment: clearly `clearInterval(timeInterval.current);` is called immediately after the interval is created ... perhaps the comment `// Clear the interval when the component unmounts` does not describe what the code is doing (the code does what it should, not what comments say) - commenting out the `clearInterval` fixes this issue - now, you just need to understand what you're doing (I don't, since I don't actually use reactjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that you are directly mutating the DOM. This is a huge React anti-pattern.

```js
const updateTime = () => {
  const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  const hours = new Date().getHours();
  const minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
  const seconds = new Date().getSeconds();

  const formattedTime = `${hours}:${minutes
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;

  document.getElementById(
    'home-time'
  ).textContent = `Last updated: ${formattedTime}`; // <-- DOM mutation!
  document.getElementById(
    'away-time'
  ).textContent = `Last updated: ${formattedTime}`; // <-- DOM mutation!
};
```

React doesn't necessarily know to rerender the page so the UI gets out-of-sync.

## Solution

I suggest adding a `updatedTime` state and rewrite the code to update the state ***and trigger a component rerender*** so the rendered DOM is kept "synchronized". Remember that in React, the rendered UI, e.g. what's rendered to the DOM, is a function of state and props.

Example:

- Create an `updatedTime` state
- Move the `updateTime` function into `useEffect` to remove it as an external dependency.
- Invoke `updateTime` once outside the interval to "seed" the time.
- Remove the conditional check that the timer is null, it starts out that way.
- Update the rendered UI to render the `updatedTime` state.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Scoreboard = () => {
  const [homeScore, setHomeScore] = useState(0);
  const [awayScore, setAwayScore] = useState(0);
  const [updatedTime, setUpdatedTime] = useState("00:00:00");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setHomeScore(data[0].id);
        setAwayScore(data[1].id);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const timeInterval = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateTime = () => {
      const hours = new Date().getHours();
      const minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
      const seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
  
      const formattedTime = `${hours}:${minutes
        .toString()
        .padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
  
      setUpdatedTime(formattedTime);
    };

    // Call once initially to "seed" state value
    updateTime();
    
    // Call the updateTime function every second
    timeInterval.current = setInterval(updateTime , 1000);

    return () => {
      // Clear the interval when the component unmounts
      clearInterval(timeInterval.current);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="scoreboard">
      <div className="team">
        <img
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f8/Barcelona_logo.svg/220px-Barcelona_logo.svg.png"
          alt="Barcelona logo"
        />
        <h1>Barcelona</h1>
        <h2>{homeScore}</h2>
        <p id="home-time">Last updated: {updatedTime}</p>
      </div>

      <div className="team">
        <img
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a2/Real_Madrid_CF.svg/220px-Real_Madrid_CF.svg.png"
          alt="Real Madrid logo"
        />
        <h1>Real Madrid</h1>
        <h2>{awayScore}</h2>
        <p id="away-time">Last updated: {updatedTime}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Scoreboard;
```

[image: Edit react-live-soccer-board-with-time]

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the if statement to check whether the interval is initialized and stored in the ref (`timeInterval.current`) then it should work.

The reason is that in the strict mode for React, the component is mounted -> unmounted -> remounted to identify potential unsafe lifecycles. This will only happen in development mode.

In this case, the `timeInterval.current` was cleaned up after it was initialized with the `setInterval`, so the interval stopped working after the initial rendering.

You should still keep the cleanup logic as a best practice for using `useEffect` in general, and also get rid of the --

```
if (!timeInterval.current) {
```

to get the interval working, especially the dependency for that `useEffect` is an empty block, ensuring that it won't get accidentally overwritten somehow.

Comment: alternatively ... `timeInterval.current = null;` after `clearInterval` - that way the rest of the logic can remain